# Jmeter 5.2.1 and Kafka

Tags: macos, heroku, apache-kafka, jmeter, apache-zookeeper

everyone, I'm testing Jmeter (5.2.1) versus a Kafka server, eventually, I will be hitting Heroku but for now, I'm testing locally.

I followed the steps from this youtube video but is not working and I cannot see why.

I installed and ran Kafka using the steps from the link below on the sources and it works fine testing from the terminal but JMETER just shows some logs but nothing else... Can anyone share some light?... Thanks!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm supposed to see the messages produced by JMeter on the consumer terminal but nothing :(

- Install Kafka Locally:
  [https://medium.com/@Ankitthakur/apache-kafka-installation-on-mac-using-homebrew-a367cdefd273].
- Video Tutorial on Windows: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6288UEUmgWA].
- Test Plan (JMX) and JSON files: [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_qG4890t_Qsqx9_X04PrScu573jzUNfI?usp=sharing].

Comment: Those serializer settings seem wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use fully qualified class names for these `kafka_message_serializer` and `kafka_key_serializer`, for example one of [these](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/package-frame.html):

[image]

for example `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer`

You might also want to try [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) as it looks like to be more up-to-date and flexible.

Check out [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter/) article for more details.

Comment: Thank Dmitry, I looked at the pepper-box option but the plugin did not load correctly... I assumed it was a version thing since all posts were on JMeter v3.. but I will try again, maybe I missed something.

Comment: I tried the pepperbox jar download but does not appear in JMeter so I went and recompiled using `mvn clean install -Djmeter.version=5.2.1 -Dkafka.version=2.4.0` but end up with errors.. Opened an issue: [https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box/issues/54]

Comment: I ended up using JMETER v3 .. I was able to test locally and now I'm moving into testing Kafka at Heroku with Jmeter